# Where did the Elves go when they said they were leaving Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings

When the Elves said they were leaving Middle-earth where were they going? For some reason I thought they were going underground. If it was another continent couldn't Sauron just build ships?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Elves become weary of their years in Middle-earth (or just too burdened with [Sea-longing](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Sea-longing)), they take ship from the [Grey Havens](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Grey_Havens) to [Valinor](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Valinor) (also known as the Undying Lands), the home of the Valar on the continent of Aman.

In the First Age, before the [Changing of the World](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Changing_of_the_World), Aman was part of Arda (the world), but after the Changing Aman was no longer in the same part of the (now spherical) world as Middle-earth and only the Elves were allowed to travel there by the [Straight Road](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Straight_Road).

Since getting to Valinor from Middle-earth requires special ships and permission ("special grace") from the Valar, Sauron would not be able to get there.